# Best way to toggle boolean on main component in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

```
// app.component.html
<div [ngClass]="{'gridLogged': isLogin, 'gridUnlogged': !isLogin}">

// app.component.ts
ngDoCheck() {

    // User is logged
    if (this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated() ) {
        this.isLogin = true;
    } else {
        this.isLogin = false;
    }
    console.log(this.isLogin);
}
```

I need to toggle `isLogin` in order to inject the css class. isLogin will toggle if user is login or not using `isAuthenticated` method.
I'm using that snippet into `ngDoCheck` because I need to check that in every different pages so I figured the main TS file would be the best place.

Problem is, it will console.log isLogin 5 times or so each time I change page so I believe this is not the best solution.

What is the best solution to toggle isLogin boolean in each time I change current route? thanks

Comment: Could you try `'gridLogged': authenticationService.isAuthenticated()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll simply answer you question : **I want to toggle isLogin each time I change current route**.

```
constructor(
  private router: Router
) {
  router.events.subscribe(events => {
    if (events instanceof NavigationEnd || events.constructor.name === NavigationEnd.name) {
      // Do your stuff here
    }
  });
```

With this code, you subscribe to route changes. But route change involves a ton of events (you can log them to see), so you will only do something on the last event, which is typed with `NavigationEnd`.

(PS : all imports come from @angular/router)